# Weird behaviour with fread

Tags: c++, readfile, fread, seek

I'm reading a binary uint32_t data from a file that indicates the size of the next binary block, after that I read that block but the reading pointer is "moving" wrong.

```
FILE* file = fopen("file.zip", "r");
long pointerA = ftell(file);
uint32_t streamSize = 0;
fread(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&streamSize), sizeof streamSize,1,file);
long pointerB = ftell(file);
char* zipData = new char[streamSize];
fread(zipData, sizeof(char),streamSize,file);

long pointerC = ftell(file);
fseek( file, pointerA + 4 + streamSize, SEEK_SET );
long pointerD = ftell(file);
qDebug()<<"streamSize"<<streamSize<<"Positions"<<pointerA<<pointerB<<pointerC<<pointerD;
```

PointerA is the original position, PointerB the position after reading that uint32_t, PointerC is the pointer after reading all that binary data and
PointerD is just a check about what I suppose that should be the right behaviour.

Now let's see the debug:

```
streamSize 2653 Positions 151 156 4627 2808
```

Why the stream read position has moved too 4627 instead 2808?

Thank you in advance for any tip!

Comment: did you open the file in binary mode? please post a [mcve]

Comment: Did you open the file in text mode instead of binary mode, by chance? Your first call to `fread()` is advancing the file position by 5 bytes instead of 4 bytes. That can happen during text mode handling, especially since `2653` contains bytes `0x0A` in it, which is a good indication that text mode is in effect. Your question is tagged C++, so why are you using C style file I/O instead of using a C++ file stream?

Comment: Remy the project is made in c++ but unfortunatly using this method was a requirement (I didn't choose it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open your file in binary mode. When a file is opened in text mode some characters are changed as you read them. For example on Windows when reading '\n' "\r\n" is returned. To open in binary mode add 'b' to your open mode, e.g:

```
FILE * file = fopen("file.txt", "rb");
```

Note you need to do the same when writing binary files otherwise the same transformations take place.

`std::fstream` also needs `std::ios_base::binary` to be passed to the constructor/open to avoid the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Both users @alan-birtles and @remy-lebeau were right, I opened it as text instead binary that was the issue.

Unfortunatly I cannot mark this as solved.

PS. For begginers this means open file with "rb" instead "r".

Comment: Ask Remy Lebeau to post comment as answer to make everyone happy.